# How can i implement a PDF reader not using UIWebView in iPad

Tags: ipad, pdf, screen-readers

How can we implement a PDF reader for iPad without using `UIWebView`? It needs the option for adding gestures for changing the page with a hand touch. How does I can do that?  What are the classes that need to be implemented for the purpose.

#### Update:

I got something like Quartz 2D programming guide for PDF Documents. But I can not identify where should i place the context of the PDF. Should i place it in a `UIView`?

Refer : http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF109

Comment: Haiii guys... I got something like Quartz 2D programming guide for PDF Documents. But i can not identify where should i place the context of the pdf. Should i place it in a UIView?. Please reply me immediately. Thanking you Sagar S. Kadookkunnan 
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF109plz refer :-

Answer (score 1):

A CGPDFDocument consists of a series of pages.  If you create a custom UIView with a CGPDFPageRef member, you can use it to draw the page.

```
@interface ExamplePDFPageView : UIView
    CGPDFPageRef page;
@end

@implementation ExamplePDFPageView
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)inFrame {
    CGContextDrawPDFPage( UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() , page );
}
@end
```

That is the basic building block from which you build a pdf reader.  You could have the view own the whole document instead of just one page, but the drawing is done per page.  I generally let some controller class own the document and assign pages to views.

For gestures, add a UISwipeGestureRecognizer or other gesture recognizer to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Read "Quartz 2D Programming Guide", and search CGPDF... functions in XCode document.